# Installed Opencv 3.4 with Anaconda Env Python Path - "No Module found"

Tags: python, anaconda, opencv, ubuntu-16.10

I installed `opencv 3.4.2` from source using this [guide](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu/)

One major change i did was point the `python-executable` to my anaconda3 `env` python3.6.

The configuration was passed successfully. However, when I activate the anaconda environment and try to import cv2. I get the `no module named cv2` still.

But the opencv installed is shown in the `conda list` as here:

```
conda list -n anaconda-env | grep -i cv
```

Ouptut is :

```
libopencv                 3.4.2                h765d7f9_1  
opencv                    3.4.2            py36h40b0b35_1  
py-opencv                 3.4.2            py36h765d7f9_1
```

Can anyone help me to know whats going wrong ? I am aware anaconda channel has a opencv pacakage. But it has only opencv3.1

Comment: Remove the current opencv package and try to re-install opencv to your current conda environment using `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`

Comment: Yes, I have tried the `menpo` channel and the one you mentioned. But both are like 3.1v . I was looking for a more like a one package installed from source and just link it to my python executable inside the env

Comment: @Deep Sorry. I did a check on the `conda-forge` again. Seems like its exactly the version I need. Not completely the way I want it though i.e One base `open-cv` built from source and then linked to any new `env` that I create. If you could elaborate on your comment and post it as an answer, I would accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The `conda-forge` organization contains one repository for each of the installable packages. Such a repository is known as a *feedstock*. A feedstock is made up of a conda recipe (the instructions on what and how to build the package) and the necessary configurations for automatic building using freely available continuous integration services.

If you want to check the Feedstock for `opencv`, it can be found [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/opencv-feedstock).

To install a package from conda-forge in a conda environment like anaconda, use : `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`